# How to import apps in another app with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, import

I would like create many indenpendants applications with a master application.

Without going into too much explanation...

- The master is the layout and functionnal core
- Apps are the contents in the master.

**Contrainsts :**

- Each applications and the master app must be have a independant repository & **can be launch (master and app too) separatly**.
- The core must called all applications

  - i would not use iframe for called applications.

I need to :
* getting all routes of all applications
* Share fonctionnal code between apps and master

What is the best approach ?

- Applications are in npm packages + lerna (or other)  ?
- Applications are build or keep dev sources in package folder ?
- Applications are vuejs plugins ?

[architecture type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OakOK.jpg)

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no silver bullet for this, but as a best practice and way to go, you should look toward **micro frontend** architecture with separate package per app + one infrastructure / common package.
Here is a good place to start: https://micro-frontends.org/